# Error message: argument should be of type: series[float]

Tags: pine-script

I have an alert condition that is triggered when the price crosses up or down DEMA (double exponential moving average) or the price is above or below DEMA.

I would also like to include an alert condition where the Tillson T3 moving average crosses up or crosses down DEMA. However, the Pine Script gives an error when I add the following sentence: '' crossover(T3_green, dema) '' or '' crossunder(T3_red, dema) '', mentioning that the argument should be of type: series[float]. Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you

```
//@version=4
study("Tillson T3 crosses DEMA 100 vs2", overlay=true)

length1 = input(3, "T3 Length")
a1 = input(0.5, "Volume Factor")

e1 = ema((high + low + 2 * close) / 4, length1)
e2 = ema(e1, length1)
e3 = ema(e2, length1)
e4 = ema(e3, length1)
e5 = ema(e4, length1)
e6 = ema(e5, length1)
c1 = -a1 * a1 * a1
c2 = 3 * a1 * a1 + 3 * a1 * a1 * a1
c3 = -6 * a1 * a1 - 3 * a1 - 3 * a1 * a1 * a1
c4 = 1 + 3 * a1 + a1 * a1 * a1 + 3 * a1 * a1
T3 = c1 * e6 + c2 * e5 + c3 * e4 + c4 * e3

col1 = T3 > T3[1]
col3 = T3 < T3[1]
color_1 = col1 ? color.green : col3 ? color.red : color.yellow
plot(T3, color=color_1, linewidth=3, title="T3")

length_DEMA = input(100, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
e7 = ema(src, length_DEMA)
e8 = ema(e7, length_DEMA)
dema = 2 * e7 - e8
plot(dema, "DEMA", color=color.purple)

T3_green = crossover(T3, T3[1])
T3_red = crossunder(T3, T3[1])

DEMA_crossover = crossover(close, dema) or close > dema or crossover(T3_green, dema)
DEMA_crossunder = crossunder(close, dema) or close < dema or crossunder(T3_red, dema)

T3_DEMA_BUY = crossover(T3, T3[1]) and DEMA_crossover
T3_DEMA_SELL = crossunder(T3, T3[1]) and DEMA_crossunder

plotshape(T3_DEMA_BUY ? low : na, text="buy", style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.large)
plotshape(T3_DEMA_SELL ? high : na, text="sell", style=shape.arrowdown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, textcolor=color.red, size=size.large)

alertcondition(T3_DEMA_BUY, title="T3 DEMA BUY", message="T3 DEMA BUY!")
alertcondition(T3_DEMA_SELL, title="T3 DEMA SELL", message="T3 DEMA SELL!")
```

Comment: `T3_green` and `T3_red` are boolean variables and can't be used in the crossover/under functions

Comment: Thanks. Are there any alternatives to circumvent the boolean variable problem?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do with that particular part of the condition. The boolean's value (true/false) can't crossover/under the `dema` value which is a float. Perhaps you just meant to have `.... and T3_green` instead of `crossover(T3_green, dema)` ?

Comment: Thanks. So, I need to convert boolean to float or use something else. What do you mean by ''' .... and T3_green '''? .... as another float?

Comment: You can't convert a boolean to a float. The crossover() function returns a boolean result by comparing two float values to see if their values crossed between the last bar and the current bar (such as two moving averages crossing each other, ie crossed ? true, didn't cross? false). Your variables `T3_green` and `T3_red` are already booleans so could be substituted as the last part of the DEMA_crossover/under lines which is what is causing the error. I don't know what it is you're trying to do exactly, so the substitution was just a guess.